Cite the name of the journal
In latex, I would like to know how can I create a command so that it cites the name of the journal. It does not has to hyper referenced. For ex. if I have the following document
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Sample bibliography
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AUTH2024,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C.},
  title = {Title of the Article},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
} 
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\citejournal{AUTH2024}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

In the above document, only the name of the journal should be printed which will come from the journal element in the bibtex of a citekey.
Thank you.

Voted to move to [tex.se].

If you prefer bibtex, you can use the usebib package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{journal}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AUTH2024,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C.},
  title = {Title of the Article},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{AUTH2024}% to make the entry appear in the bibliography

\usebibentry{AUTH2024}{journal}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}



This is very easy if you switch from bibtex to biblatex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AUTH2024,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C.},
  title = {Title of the Article},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}{}{\printfield{journaltitle}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\cite{AUTH2024}

\citejournal{AUTH2024}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


